# reading javascript variables within enqueued JS files in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have `main.js` file which is like this. I would like to read `departDateOneWay` in `sample.js`

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.on('load', function () {
        var $document = $(document);
     ...
     ...

          function(start, end) {
       
          departDateOneWay = start.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
          console.log("onewaydepart:::"+departDateOneWay);
          var testVar ='<?php echo $departDateOneWay;?>';
       }
       
     ...
     ...

    });

})(jQuery);
```

In  `sample.js` file , which is called in an `onclick` event, I am expecting to see the `testVar` but I am not sure if that is the correct way as I get `testVar is not defined`

```
function test(){
    console.log("departdate:"+testVar);
}
```

I am enqueuing both `sample.js` and `main.js` like this in `functions.php`

```
function travel_register_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/main.js', array(), '1.0', false);
   wp_enqueue_script('sample', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/sample.js', array(), '1.0', false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'travel_register_scripts');
```

I also tried wrapping the whole `main.js` file in php this way so I could read `departDateOneWay` in `sample.js`

```
    <script type='text/javascript>
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        var $window = $(window);
     ...
        function(start, end) {           
          departDateOneWay = start.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
          console.log("onewaydepart:::"+departDateOneWay);
          var testVar ='<?php echo $departDateOneWay; ?>';
       }
     ...
</script>
 <?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'ti_custom_javascript');
?>
```

but as soon as I enqueue the newly created `main.php` (from main.js) instead of `main.js` , site does not load

Basically  I would like to read javascript variables from one JS file to another where all JS files are enqueued using `wp_enqueue_scripts` . Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the scope of the `departDateOneWay` variable: it's localized to the callback function for `window.load`.

In `main.js`, set the `departDateOneWay` value as a property on the `window` object, and then access in `sample.js` by doing `window.departDateOneWay`.

`main.js`

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.on('load', function () {
        var $document = $(document);
     ...
     ...

          function(start, end) {
       
          window.departDateOneWay = start.format('YYYY/MM/DD');
          console.log("onewaydepart:::"+window.departDateOneWay);
       }
       
     ...
     ...

    });

})(jQuery);
```

`sample.js`

```js
function test(){
    console.log("departdate:"+window.departDateOneWay);
}
```